# PySpark: TypeError: StructType can not accept object 0.10000000000000001 in type <type 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

when using PySpark with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
samples = np.array([0.1,0.2])
dfSchema = StructType([StructField("x", FloatType(), True)])
spark.createDataFrame(samples,dfSchema)
```

I get:

> TypeError: StructType can not accept object 0.10000000000000001 in type 
>   type 'numpy.float64'>

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NumPy types, including `numpy.float64`, are not a valid external representation for Spark SQL types. Furthermore schema you use doesn't reflect the shape of the data.

You should use standard Python types, and corresponding `DataType` directly:

```
spark.createDataFrame(samples.tolist(), FloatType()).toDF("x")
```

Comment: Yeah. I had to first use `float(x)` to convert a value x in an RDD which is a numpy.float64 before calling `toDF`